# jQuery onclick bug for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form:

```
<form name="registration_form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>user/register" method="post" onsubmit="return verify()">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
   <tr>
       <td class="login_user_td">Click If Want To Edit :</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="edit" id="edit" onclick="enable_edit()"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="login_user_td"> First Name :</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="f_name" readonly="true" id="f_name" value="<?php echo $my_info[0]['first_name'];?>">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2" align="center" class="login_user_button"><input type="image" style="display: none;"src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front_assets/image/edit.gif" /></td>
     </tr>

   </table>
   </form>
```

Now the checkbox edit have a onclick event which calls the function

```
enable_edit()
{
        if($('#edit').prop("checked", true))
             {
                 alert('true');
             }
        else
                 alert('false');
    }
```

The problem is that, whenever I am clicking on the checkbox, it's always displaying true.

Suppose if I click first time, the property gets checked, then it will alert true, next time when I am again clicking, this time the check should get unchecked, and hence should alert false.

But every time it's alerting true, moreover the checkbox isn't getting unchecked.

Comment: You're using the *setter* form of `prop()` in your example. Did you mean `if ($("#edit").prop("checked"))` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are always setting the checked state rather than querying it.

Use `prop("checked")` instead of `prop("checked", true)` in your conditional check as the latter will always set the `checked` state property to `true`.

See [**.prop() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more details on getting and setting a property value.

Change your code to the following:

```
function enable_edit() {
  if ($('#edit').prop("checked")) {
    alert('true');
  } else alert('false');
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vqpLY/) - Working checkbox

---

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the value of the checked attribute to true in that if statement.

What you need is just `$('#edit').prop("checked");`

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#edit').prop("checked") {

}
```

is probably a better test.

Comment: The second parameter of prop() will assign a value to the property. So your test will allways be true.